# The total sum of all the values

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, ubuntu-18.04

I'm learning ubuntu bash script and i'm having some trouble, i didn't want to ask this cuz probably the solution is going to be very obvious, but here we are...

I want to get the sum of the values.

So in this case the sum is 90.

**What does the code do:**

If the value of the first parameter is 2, a message with the value of the first parameter will be displayed first. 
 
Using the for loop, print out the value of the third parameter multiplied by values ​​from 1 to values ​​of the second parameter.

This is input in the terminal: `./param.sh 2 5 6`

This is code output:

```
6 * 1 = 6
6 * 2 = 12
6 * 3 = 18   
6 * 4 = 24
6 * 5 = 30
```

This is the code output i want:

```
6 * 1 = 6
6 * 2 = 12
6 * 3 = 18  
6 * 4 = 24
6 * 5 = 30
Total sum is 90
```

Here is code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == 2 ]
then
    echo "the first parameter has value " $1
for(( a = 1; a <= $2; a++ ))
do
    res=$[ $3 * $a ]
    echo " $3 * $a = $res "
done
fi

//we need.. echo "Total sum is "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for bash arithmetic evaluation:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 == 2 ]
then
    echo "the first parameter has value " $1
for(( a = 1; a <= $2; a++ ))
do
    ((res=$3 * a))
    echo " $3 * $a = $res "
    ((sum+=res))
done
fi


echo "Sum is: $sum"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have just a finit arithmetic series, you could calculate it directly as

```
echo "Sum is: $(( ($2*$3*($2+1))/2 ))"
```